# Geometric Picture of Open Subsets of Irreducible spaces in Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, zariski-topology

I understand why nonempty open subsets of irreducible topological spaces are dense. I am having trouble comprehending how this translates to Zariski's topology. We know that a finite affine variety is irreducible iff it is a single point. How do you take an open subset of a single point? What does this look like geometrically?

Comment: The statement "an affine variety is irreducible iff it is a single point" is not true. How did you come to that?

Comment: @KReiser Andreas Gathmann Chapter 2; example 2.11: "A finite affine variety is irreducible if and only if it is connected: namely if and only if it
contains at most one point." Am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio ^

Comment: Lots of varieties are not finite! For instance, $\Bbb A^1$.

Comment: @KReiser You are right. I mean my question with respect to finite affine varieties. So not $\mathbb{A}^n$

Comment: The topology on a point is pretty simple. I bet you can write down explicitly what it is.

Comment: So the open subset of a point is just the empty set?

Comment: No, that's not correct. Any topology on a set $X$ must contain the entire set $X$ and the empty set $\varnothing$. Can there be any other open sets in a topology on a single point?

Comment: X is an open set, so the open subset of a point is just the point itself? Sorry, I am taking so long to process this it just seems so unintuitive.

Comment: The unique topology on a one-point set $X=\{pt\}$ has open sets $X$ and $\varnothing$. So the only open subsets of a topological space consisting of a point are the whole space $\{pt\}$ and the empty set. The only nonempty open subset is $\{pt\}$, the whole space.